Unable to delete older stackexchange.com filters
Answering possible questions, yes I read the question
How can I delete my custom search filter?
and no, it DOES NOT WORK for me.
When I try to delete my own filters from here created long ago, they are not deleted. Pushing the highlighted button just gives them the generic name my filter and they stay as is, only updating their ID in the URL.

The right menu from the question above is empty

I assume this happens because the filter were created for the email that is no longer in my account. Is it? How to resolve this?

To confirm my understanding: you can delete newly created filters, just not older ones, correct?

yes, exactly like this

Can't delete the filter called My Filter

thanks, didn't notice this Q. This bug is already 5 yo, but nobody cares to fix it, lol

"I read the question How can I delete my custom search filter? and no, it DOES NOT WORK for me." along with this screenshot of yours and "I assume this happens because the filter were created for the email that is no longer in my account. Is it?" custom filters and the network-wide tag filters are two completely different features. There is no overlap in functionality. Network filters don't show up as custom filters and vice versa.

ok, agree, my title about custom filters was confusing. Anyway, the fact that bug with network-wide filters exists for years and nobody fixes it, is embarrassing
